# Close MySQL Connection Without Waiting for Response in Flask

Tags: python, mysql, flask, sqlalchemy

I'm using MySQL through SQLAlchemy in a Flask App. In situations where I need to use a db connection, I can see that closing that connection at the end of a request means that I have to wait for a `ROLLBACK` to be run on the connection against my database, which means waiting for an extra request to travel to the database and back. In my geographical situation, waiting for the extra time for this to happen can take >100ms. This seems like a very avoidable cost as there is really no reason to make a user submitting a request to wait for this final back-and-forth with the database.

Is there any reason not to close the connection asynchronously, or somehow after the response has been sent back to the user? Is there an accepted way of doing this?